# ¿Cómo generar una tabla en un PDF?

Tags: python, django

Estoy generando una tabla, pero marca el `Table` en rojo y no sé que librería importar `(tabla = Table([fila1,fila2,fila3,fila4]))`
esto lo hago para despues pegarlo en una PDF

```
fila1 = ['','Lunes','Martes','Miércoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado','Domingo']
fila2 = ['Mañana','Estudiar','Gimnasio','-','-','-','Estudiar','Ir a la iglesia']
fila3 = ['Tarde','Trabajar','Trabajar','Trabajar','Trabajar','Trabajar','-','-']
fila4 = ['Noche','Trabajar','Trabajar','Trabajar','Trabajar','-','-','-']
```

Definimos la tabla.

```
tabla = Table([fila1,fila2,fila3,fila4])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo utilizo una librería llamada weasyPrint en la que puedes utilizar una plantilla HTML y puedes maquetar el PDF como quieras. Te adjunto a librería y un ejemplo en código.[WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

### templates/home_page.html

```
    <html>
     <head>
         Home Page
     </head>
     <body>
      <h1>Hello !!!</h1>
      <p>First Pdf Generation using Weasyprint.</p>
     </body>
    </html>
```

### Funcion

```
from weasyprint import HTML, CSS
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.http import HttpResponse

    def pdf_generation(request):
        html_template = get_template('templates/home_page.html')
        pdf_file = HTML(string=html_template).write_pdf()
        response = HttpResponse(pdf_file, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="home_page.pdf"'
        return response
```

Comment: la estoy generando de esta manera

Comment: excelente se ve facil, dejame intentarlo F Delgado, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

estoy intentnado realizarla de esta manera, solo que nose como agregarsela al PDF ya existente en python --> me arroja este error 'list' object has no attribute 'split' en esta linea ( parrafo = Paragraph(story, 
estilos['subtitulo']) )

```
story = []
datos = (
    ('Nombre ciclo', 'Núm. Alumnos', 'Núm aprobados'),
    ('Desarrollo Aplic. Informáticas', 15, 5),
    ('Admin. Sist. Informáticos', 40, 25),
    ('Explotación Sist. Informáticos', 50, 20)
)
tabla = Table(data=datos,
              style=[
                  ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.5, colors.grey),
                  ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 2, colors.black),
                  ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.pink),
              ]
              )
story.append(tabla)
parrafo = Paragraph(story,
                    estilos['subtitulo'])
parrafo.wrapOn(can, 6 * cm, 5 * cm)
parrafo.drawOn(can, 16.5 * cm, 6.5 * cm)


can.showPage()
can.save()

output = PdfFileWriter()

packet.seek(0)
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(RECURSOS_DIR + "pdf/hoja_cobranza.pdf", "rb"))
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)

page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)

output.write(response)
return response
```